# PlayFramework excludes null value when converting Json to DynamicForm

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm posting a simple json document below to my Play Framework application. Below json document only contains key/values that have been changed/updated by the user.

```
{ "id": "abc", "first_name": "Mark", "last_name": null, "city": "NY" }
```

I'm then using `Map<String, String> mapParameters = Form.forms().bindFromRequest().data` to get the json document data as key/value pair map for updating my user document.

However, the converted `Map<String, String>` does ***NOT*** contain key entry for "last_name", which has value of null.

Therefore, I don't have a clear way to differentiate above json document from the below json document, which did **NOT** intentionally include "last_name" key/value because "last_name" was not changed/updated by the user.

```
{ "id": "abc", "first_name": "Matt", "city": "NJ" }
```

Is there any reason why PlayFramework is ignoring the key/value all together if the value is null?
and is there different way to get the converted `Map<String, String>` which will include all keys in the json document even if the value is null?

I hope my question is clear and just to be clear, the first json document above is to delete the last_name and the second json document is to keep the existing last_name as is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried the above json and at server code I get the values with request().body().asJson(), it is working fine. I am getting null values as well.